# Adding median and quartile range to multiple grouped violin plot in R

Tags: r, median, violin-plot

I use the following code in R to produce a violin plot for 5 variables ("CAP1-5") across 3 groups (BP, BPoff, HC). This code worked:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = CAP, y = Value, fill = GROUP)) +
  geom_violin(scale = "width", trim = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("BP" = "red", "BPoff" = "grey", "HC" = "white")) +
  xlab("CAP") +
  ylab("Value") +
  theme_minimal() +
  facet_wrap(~ CAP, scales = "free_x", nrow = 1)
(output attached).
```

But I would like to insert median and quartile to each violin plot, and I manage to add it only in the middle one for each variable adding the lines of code below, how can I do this?

```
geom_point(data = summary_data, aes(x = CAP, y = median), shape = 23, size = 3, fill = "white") +
  geom_errorbar(data = summary_data, aes(x = CAP, ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.2, color = "black") +
```

Thank you so much!
Best
[image: I manage to add median and quartile only in the middle plot for each variable]

Comment: What does `summary_data` look like?  Do you have estimates for all 3 groups?  If you do, try setting `group = GROUP` within the `aes` function for `geom_point` and `geom_errorbar`

Comment: Thank you so much Melissa! summary_data is a tibble 15x4 with the median and quartile range for each violin. 

I added "group = GROUP" in the code:
geom_point(data = summary_data, aes(x = CAP, y = median, group = GROUP), shape = 23, size = 3, fill = "white") +   geom_errorbar(data = summary_data, aes(x = CAP, ymin = lower, ymax = upper, group = GROUP), width = 0.2, color = "black")

but got the error below: 

 Error in `geom_point()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'GROUP' not found

Comment: Tried this code, the median/quartiles is only present for BPoff, not for the other groups. 
ggplot(data_long, aes(x = CAP, y = Value, fill = GROUP)) +
  geom_violin(scale = "width", trim = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("BP" = "red", "BPoff" = "grey", "HC" = "white")) +
  stat_summary(data = data_long, fun = median, geom = "point", shape = 23, size = 3, fill = "white") +
  stat_summary(data = data_long, fun.data = median_hilow, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2, color = "black") +
  xlab("CAP") +  ylab("Value") +  theme_minimal() +   facet_wrap(~ CAP, scales = "free_x", nrow = 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options to add quartiles to your plot.

first is to use the `draw_quartiles` parameter in `geom_violin_plot`

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(group=rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=100),
                 var=rep(c("CAP1","CAP2","CAP3","CAP4","CAP5"), times=60),
                 value=rnorm(300))

summ_df <- df %>% group_by(group, var) %>% summarize(median=median(value),
                                                     Lower=quantile(value, probs=0.25),
                                                     Upper=quantile(value, probs=0.75)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = median:Upper, names_to = "quantile", values_to = "estimate")

df %>% ggplot(aes(x=var, y=value, fill=group)) + 
  geom_violin(scale="width", trim=FALSE, draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))
```

[image]

second, is to use `geom_point` with a dataframe containing the summary estimates and `position_dodge` to get them spaced appropriately

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(x=var, y=value, fill=group)) + 
  geom_violin(scale="width", trim=FALSE) + 
  geom_point(data = summ_df, aes(x=var, y=estimate, group=group), 
             position = position_dodge(width=0.9))
```

[image]

third is to use `stat_summary` and `Hmisc`

```
stat_sum_df <- function(fun, geom="crossbar", ...) {
  stat_summary(fun.data = fun, colour = "red", geom = geom, width = 0.2, ...)
}

df %>% ggplot(aes(x=var, y=value, fill=group)) + 
     geom_violin(scale="width", trim=FALSE) + 
  stat_sum_df("median_hilow", mapping = aes(group = group), position=position_dodge(width=0.9))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you this is extremely clear, helpful, and kind. all solutions worked perfectly. thanks!!!